# Latin Modern Math doesn't have boldface

Tags: xetex

The following code does not show bold characters; why?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\author{ME}
\title{SOME FANCY TITLE}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[version=lm]

\begin{document}
\maketitle
ABC 
\textbf{ABC}
def
\end{document}
```

I guess I'm missing some fonts, but a fast

```
fc-list | grep "Latin Modern"
```

gives me only

```
/usr/share/fonts/latinmodern-math.otf: Latin Modern Math:style=Regular
```

which is the only file I find at the [LM Math website](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math/download/index_html).

So, what's up?

Comment: `\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}`; remove `[version=lm]`. Why would you want to use a math font for text?

Comment: Oh, so Latin Modern Math extends only the mathematical alphabet? I might have misunderstood its function. But I have the same problem when I replace `\textbf{ABC}` with `$\mathbf{ABC}$`, so the question remains.

Comment: I have no issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should specify a *text* font for `\setmainfont`. Also don't specify `version`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\author{ME}
\title{SOME FANCY TITLE}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

ABC
\textbf{ABC}
def $\mathbf{iff}\ne\symbf{iff}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `unicode-math` there are two ways of specifying boldface in math: with `\mathbf` you ask for the bold text font, with `\symbf` you ask for bold math letters from the math font.

Comment: I realized I didn't have the Latin Modern Roman fonts. That was the issue.